# c language, pointer arithmetics

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code

```
void main(void) {
    int data = 0x5555;
    int* dataptr = &data;
    int** dataptrptr = &dataptr;
    int*** dataptrptrptr = &dataptrptr;
    printf("%d\n", ***dataptrptrptr);
}
```

`data` is at address `0xabcd`

`dataptr` is at address `0x1234`

`dataptrptr` is at address `0x8888`

`dataptrptrptr` is at address `0xffff`

Is the effective address being read by `*((*dataptrptrptr) + 4)` `0x8888 + 4 = 0x888c`?

Also, is the value of the expression `**dataptrptrptr` 0x1234?

Comment: How do you know the adresses of these (machine dependent) variables? Have you written a program to print these out? Or are these an hypothese? Anyway, for adjacent variables, the probability is high that these do not differ as much as in the examples given.

Comment: @PierreFrançois this may be a homework assignment in which case the values would be given. OP, taking your numbers at face value... as a hint, `&dataptrptr` is the address of `dataptrptr`. So if you say, *`dataptrptr` is at address `0x8888`* that means the value of `&dataptrptr` is `0x8888`. What does that say about the contents of `dataptrptrptr`?

Comment: In any case, adding `4` to a pointer in C doesn't increase its value by `4` but by `4 * sizeof (*int)`.

Comment: @PierreFrançois "adding 4 to THIS pointer". I would mostly agree had you used a definite article.

Comment: ...adds 4 times the size of what is being pointed to.

Comment: @WeatherVane *much* better

Comment: @JeffHolt: that's what I mean. I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: @JeffHolt answered the question and I make his words mine _In any case, adding 4 to a pointer in C doesn't increase its value by 4 but by 4 * sizeof (*int)_

Comment: Pointer arithmetic means that the compiler knows the size of the data being pointed and multiply the index by the size of the data. If you say `addr + N` you're telling the compiler that you want _Nth_ value starting from _addr_. If there something there or not is totally your problem, not of the compiler

Comment: regarding: `void main(void) `  although some non-conforming compilers allow that signature for `main()` there are only two conforming signatures: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Answer (score 2):

> Is the effective address being read by *((*dataptrptrptr) + 4) 0x8888 + 4 = 0x888c?

Maybe - it depends

`*dataptrptrptr` is `0x8888`, yet addresses are not simple as integers.

Adding 4 to 0x8888 as integers is 0x888C.

As a pointer, adding 4 to `int**` 0x8888 is forming the address 4 `int**` pointers further along in memory.

**If** a `int **` pointer is 8 bytes and **if** the addresses increment on byte address, the expected sum is `int**` 0x88A8.

**If** a `int **` pointer is 4 bytes and **if** the addresses increment on byte address, the expected sum is `int**` 0x8898.

**If** a `int **` pointer is N bytes and **if** `int **` live in a special place in memory where address are in N bytes chunks, the expected sum is `int**` 0x888C.

But other possibilities exist: 0x8890, pointer_street:0x0004, *undefined behavior*, etc.

Pointer math is not integer math.

---

The value of the expression `**dataptrptrptr` is the `int *` pointer 0x1234.